# ubuntu 14.04 not working after kernel update how can I save my ubuntu system?

Tags: 14.04, kernel

ubuntu 14.04 not working after kernel update how can I save my ubuntu system?

yesterday , when I updated the ubuntu 14.04 and its kernel core , it  asked me for a reboot! and then I cant access to my ubuntu , but it shows grub page corectly and after enter to it I see just a black page

how can I save my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the new kernel doesn't have the modules that comes with your proprietary driver and fails to use your configuration files. If you still have the boot menu that comes with a default Ubuntu installation then you can choose "Recovery mode". In the next menu choose to boot into safe mode, and if Ubuntu asks if you want to create a new configuration file just allow it to do so. There should be other ways to generate new configuration (like deleting some dot files) but I just know this way.
Then when everything is OK reinstall the graphic driver.
Edit: to boot into recovery mode see the question [How do I prevent GRUB from using/starting any graphical UI?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4027/250)

Comment: I did it but not working

Comment: @younesnoori you did what it said in link i gave below?

Comment: yes I did what it said in link

Comment: try this, press shift when you turn on your PC, then you must see list where you can select old kernel version in Grub. try to start ubuntu like this and tell me.